# Write conflict: I want to always Drop Changes

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a split database and I have duplicated front-end file to make multiple copies for different users. Every-time a change is made on one front-end form, I want the other forms in other front-ends to always drop changes. How can I trap this write conflict to always drop changes maybe through VBA if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by "drop changes" - the frontend should never be redesigned during normal use.

You must distribute a new copy of the frontend to the users.

A smooth and proven method using a *shortcut* and a *script* is described in my article:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html)

*(If you don't have an account, browse for the link: Read the full article)*

**Edit**:

If it is the data that is updated by several users, and you update via VBA, you may study another of my articles:

[Handle concurrent update conflicts in Access silently](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/25780/Handle-concurrent-update-conflicts-in-Access-silently.html)

Though simple to use, the code is a bit too much to post here. It is also on **GitHub**:

[VBA.ConcurrencyUpdates](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ConcurrencyUpdates)

Comment: I think OP means this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/write-conflict-dialog-box-2d139ce4-4ec5-4bea-adb2-b2a3d73ee775

Comment: @Andre: Right. I misread the question. I've edited the answer.